# How do I override/add parameters using Azure AZ

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Previously my script looked like this using AzureRM

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
-Name LocalTestDeployment `
-ResourceGroupName xxx-${env}-${location} `
-Mode Incremental `
-TemplateFile ..\webapp\azuredeploy.json `
-TemplateParameterFile ..\webapp\azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json `
-azureEnvironment ${env} `
-locationKey ${location}
```

How would I do the same in Azure AZ?

This is how far I have gotten from what I can find in the documentation, but how do I do with the last two lines where I override/add extra properties to the template?

```
az group deployment create `
--name LocalTestDeployment `
--resource-group xxx-${env}-${location} `
--mode Incremental `
--template-file ..\webapp\azuredeploy.json `
--parameters `@..\webapp\azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json `
-azureEnvironment ${env} `
-locationKey ${location}
```

Comment: i dont think az cli supports that

Comment: So how would I go about doing it dynamically? especially when I would like to test things in different environments/regions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a closer look at the documentation and found this example:

```
az group deployment create -g MyResourceGroup --template-file azuredeploy.json \
                        --parameters @params.json --parameters https://mysite/params.json --parameters MyValue=This MyArray=@array.json
```

Looks like I missed the last part of that example earlier, when I tried that it worked as expected.

Working example:

```
az group deployment create `
--name LocalTestDeployment `
--resource-group xxx-${env}-${location} `
--mode Incremental `
--template-file ..\webapp\azuredeploy.json `
--parameters `@..\webapp\azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json `
--parameters azureEnvironment=${env} locationKey=${location}
```

Comment: yeah, like I said, I'm not exactly az cli user. glad you sorted it out

Comment: Yeah, funny how I sometimes tear my hair out for a while and then ask the question here to see if anyone can help and then shortly after posting the question find the answer myself :p